# How to use sep command with sorted

Tags: python

I want to separate sorted numbers with "<", but can't do it.

Here is the code:

```
numbers = [3, 7, 5]
print(sorted(numbers), sep="<")
```

Comment: Does ``print(*sorted(numbers), sep="<")`` (note the ``*``) do what you want?

Comment: This is not executable code; for one thing `a`, `b` and `c` are not defined.

Comment: `sep` defines the character to print between objects, which is a space by default. `sorted` returns a `list`, and as it is `print` is printing the entire list object. Use `print(*sorted(numbers), sep="<")` to apply the separator to individual list elements, as MisterMiyagi said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator as mentioned by @MisterMiyagi, can be used to unpack the list variables and use the `sep`.

Code:

```py
print(*sorted(numbers), sep="<")
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is the answer you want, but I have made a python code to seperate the sorted numbers with "<" with join after I convert the numbers to strings.

As the items in the iterable must be string types, I first use a list comprehension to create a list containing each interger as a string, and pass this as input to str.join()

```py
# Initial String
test_str = [5,1,2,3,4]
# Sorting number
sortedNum = sorted(test_str)
# Changing numbers into string
string_ints = [str(int) for int in sortedNum]
# Joining the sorted string with "<"
output = '<'.join(string_ints)
print(output)
```